# Pick the first duplicat value ($R$4:$R) based on each of them must be have high number on column ($T$4:$T) with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I want to make a duplicat value which are refferance from ($R$4:$R) column. Based on each have a highest number of them on column of ($T$4:$T) as a criteria and want to do this all with arrayformula.

I've tried my formula on "T E S T" column on (AE3) but it doesn't gave me the rights output as I want as I imagine it.

See the pic I atteched here below :
[image: Example pic]

And my gsheet's doc please feel free to edit because I hope that you will. It makes me happy  ^_^  :
[Example link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HkmdETZ28bFPXK9XjtOga-achVqmkO9AvO5lHLQDc8U/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster I've just tried to fix and learnig earlier how to make the questions better in here. And I've try it to make a new one but then why my question still have doesn't approved yet in this community ?  Here it is where I'm posting it my new one with the new subject is "GET DUPLICATE VALUES FROM COLUMN R3:R TO ANOTHER COLUMN ON AD3:AD THEN MAKE IT AS A NEW NAME IF DUPLICATE MORE THEN ONE GROUP DEPEND ON COLUMN F3:F"

Comment: Jamal Don't SHOUT in titles. It attracts attention and scrutiny from other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula. It seems to work in Column AF

```
=filter(If(IFERROR(match(R4:R,R:R,0),0)=ROW(R4:R),R4:R,""),R4:R<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanksfully to you PG. It makes me happy indeed you save me the time !

Comment: I've just realized that those your formula can't do the exactly what I want because while the data keeps coming for couple rows with the same names but differenced by only position with 1 row or several rows not by sorted them by grouping or not seperated them by any rows so the expactation result of output supposed be get their new names too ..